# Does anyone knows a good Facebook chat script?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, ajax, chat

I'm looking for a facebook chat script.. that can handle a large number of users.. does anyone knows one? I need one urgent and please post one that you had experience with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CometChat](http://www.cometchat.com/), it's allow your site users to chat with each other (all online users or only friends) in real-time. Your users can also chat with their Facebook/Gtalk friends or even connect to your own Jabber/XMPP server; all, seamlessly from the CometChat bar.

CometChat can be installed (with automatic login, friends list sync and status, avatars & profile linking) on these platforms without any programming knowledge:

JomSocial, vBulletin, SocialEngine, Invision Power Board, phpFox, Boonex Dolphin, BuddyPress, phpBB, WordPress, SkaDate, Elgg, xenForo, Small Machines Forum and many more.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, but while you posted this I just found this facebook chat script wich is also a comet chat alternative called NxChat. I talked with them and the guys from the support were kind enough to even install it for me. Its so blazing fast, faster than cometchat wich i already knew off.. If anyone tried it before, please tell me, this is their website http://noxien.com/facebook-chat-script . They said that it supports a large number of users online, without overloading the server at all, but i want to know your experience with it, because i want another one for a bigger website.